# Is Redux store middleware an example of the Chain of Responsibility design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, redux-middleware

Is Redux store middleware an example of the Chain of Responsibility design pattern? If not, what design pattern does it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a simple implementation of the Chain Of Responsibility Pattern. When an action is dispatched to the middleware, it checks that is is suitable for his porpouse. If not, the action is passed to the next middleware that can take care of it.